# Перенос слова "Москва"

Tags: орфография, перенос

На сайте грамота.ру задали вопрос - "Как правильно переносить слово "Москва"?" И был ответ: "Мо-сква, Моск-ва и Мос-ква" (при этом отметили, что второй вариант нежелателен).
С третьим вариантом я полностью согласен, а вот первый и второй повергли в недоумение. И, если насчет "Моск-вы" еще оговорились, то первый вариант дали как верный. Может быть, я чего-то не понимаю, но разве так можно переносить? Ведь слоги тут "мос-ква", плюс при переносе правильно разрывать две согласные, стоящие подряд.
Что скажут об этом специалисты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут несколько моментов.
~1. Де-юре все три варианта возможны. Правила переноса сейчас стали более свободными, но даже раньше требования "при переносе правильно разрывать две согласные, стоящие подряд" не существовало. Главным было требование не нарушать морфемную структуру слова, т.е. по возможности переносить на стыках приставки и корня, корня и суффикса - и т.д. С появлением в 90-х годах компьютерной верстки это правило де-факто перестало существовать как императивное.

~2. "Деление на слоги" для правил переноса - даже в период их актуальности - несколько отличалось от фонетического. При фонетическом подходе используется принцип нарастающей звучности, другими словами при скоплении согласных слогораздел проходит перед наименее звучной согласной (или последней из них, если их несколько). Само понятие "звучности" несколько размыто, но в любой случае наименее звучными считаются глухие шумные (свистящие и шипящие), а наиболее звучными - сонорные. Применительно к нашему случаю фонетический слогораздел должен быть *мо-сква* или *мос-ква*. Но с точки зрения наглядности лучшим при стечении согласных считается перенос перед последней согласной. Т.е "моск-ва"

~3. Однако "ква" лучше не разделять переносом с исторической точки зрения. Ква - это рефлекс древнего "КЫ", его лучше сохранить цельным.

~4. Топонимы стоит переносить только по стыкам морфемных составляющих, а топонимы без ясно выраженного морфологического деления лучше вообще не переносить. имхо.

Таким образом, если без переноса никак не обойтись, то идеальным следует признать "Мос-ква", но два других варианта также вполне возможны.

Comment: ...если без переноса никак не обойтись.


Таких жёстких условий и раньше-то не было, а уж сейчас только по случаю лени великой верстальщик не станет избегать переноса. Надеюсь, здесь не говорится о трудностях рукописи.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно ПАСУ (Полный академический справочник) такой перенос возможен. [Правила переноса](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)